# Make sidebar thats longer than browser but not longer than content that scrolls together

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've looked everywhere but I couldn't find the right solution

The sidebar is long but there's still white space when I get to the end because it's not the length of the content. So, I was thinking maybe having it 'fixed' using jquery but the thing is, is that it's still a long sidebar.. So is there a way for me to have the sidebar scroll gradually as I scroll so that it reaches the bottom of the sidebar the same time it I reach the footer?

I thought about something maybe like "(0, sidebarTop - scrollTop)" with 'sidebartop' being the position ('top' increases as you scroll so it pushes the sidebar down) but it not working right.. it's actually pushing it up

I'm a bit sleep deprived and I may not be thinking about it clear at the moment but I need to figure this out for a client due saturday..

You see how the sidebar long? (shorten your browser) -- I would like it so that the sidebar will move gradually down with the content just like this

Comment: "jsfiddle": http://jsfiddle.net/VEsdu/

Comment: Let me get this straight. It's taller than the window so you can't use a "fix to position" type thing, you want it to scroll at a different speed to the content so it's bottom and the footer align when the page reaches the point where you can't scroll down any more?

Comment: Ah, checked your link, that is what you want. I need to sleep now but I would think you'd want to use the ratio of document height over sidebar height to find a percentage by which the sidebar scrolls compared to the real scroll distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need little extra math: http://jsfiddle.net/VEsdu/317/

```
scrolled = Math.min(1, (scrollTop - sidebarTop)/(ch - wh));
topPosition += scrolled * (ch - sh);
```

On the first line we get what part of content in the viewport - 0 for top of content at viewport top, 1 for bottom of content at viewport bottom.
On the second line adding the margin to sidebar proportional to difference between content/sidebar heights.

I'm not sure this will work with viewport taller than sidebar/content or after window resize, you should check that cases.

Comment: Ok, this is working on my testing environment. The only thing is that it's moving my sidebar up (using negative "top") instead of down

Comment: Wait sorry.. Easy fix.. This works, I just added a couple adjustments to & its working perfectly! I can finally rest! Thanks @antejan.. I'll post my final one a little later once I get it perfect but yours should work for anyone but will maybe need minor adjustments

Comment: One problem, it's only working properly on after a refresh.. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, here's a fix.. use this (it may cause other problems but it's a start) -> $(window).load(function()